# SQL Rounding Problems in 2005 and 2000

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, rounding, rounding-error

I have a value in the database which is 2.700000002. When I run a query in Management studio in SQL SERVER 2005 I get 2.7. But when I run in SQL SERVER 2000 query analyzer it comes 2.700000002.

2.70000002 is correct why is SQL SERVER 2005 trying to change the value by rounding it or selecting the floor value?

Comment: what do you have set for your default numeric formatting in your SS2005 instance?

Comment: What datatypes are you using, can you post a code snippet?

Comment: What are the data types, that you are using? Or the table schema/ query for that matter

Comment: data type is float and it displays fine in sql server 2000 query analyzer. I guess I should check out default numeric formatting as DaveE suggested!

Comment: How do you change the default numeric formatting in SS2005?

Comment: @azamsharp - check the properties of the column you're having trouble with and make sure they're appropriate. (in Management Studio, Object Explorer, right-click on the column, Properties; check precision & scale) We've had ODBC settings affect numeric formats in the results in the past but I don't remember what specifically was hurting us. (connectionstrings.com can help)

Comment: I agree with JohnFX: table schema + code please would help.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same target server, database, datatype, processor, architecture etc?

If not, it's simply how the tools will display an approximate float value

Comment: This seems as helpfull as the *approximate float value*

Comment: Everything exactly the same but SS2005 displays 2.7 and SS2000 displays 2.700000002. Some sort of settings I need to change in SS2005?

Answer (score 0):

Most things round off numbers for display.

```
~$ ghci
Prelude> 2.7
2.7
~$ irb
>> 2.7
=> 2.7
~$ python
>>> 2.7
2.7000000000000002
```

For interactive use, this is usually good enough — the only person to see the query analyzer is you, so why does it matter? For actual display, you should specify a format anyway. If you really need the exact value of `"2.7"`, then you should be using a decimal type anyway, as countless articles and answers can tell you.

Comment: That is not the question! The question is how do I get the same result in SS2005. SS2000 displays 2.70000002 which is what I want to see in SS2005!!